# Relays making TCA9534 I2C bus expander reset when driving AC inductive loads

Tags: microcontroller, relay, i2c

I have a PCB which uses a TCA9534 as an IO bus expander. It has four relays interfaced via MOSFETs.

This board is connected via ribbon cable to the main board, which contains the main MCU that controls this TCA9534. Main board also provides stabilized +5V for TCA9534.

Everything works fine when no external load is connected to the relays. However if an inductive load is connected, when the relay contacts open and close, the TCA9534 loses configuration bytes from configuration registers, and all interface pins become inputs. I guess that the chip is being reset.

This is the schematic fragment including TCA9534:

[image: partial schematic including TCA9534]

And this is the circuity of one of the relays:

[image: partial schematic showing one of the relays]

This is the designed layout:

[image: image of PCB layout]

As you can see, I placed a bypass capacitor near the TCA9534 to avoid incoming noise.

Note that there are more chips in the design, but they are not causing problems. They are not being used at the moment the problems occur.

As a workaround, I placed a MOV in parallel with relay switch and apparently the problem disappeared. As best as I can understand, the MOV is limiting high voltage spikes caused by the relay contact arcing.

Even though the problem might been solved, I have seen tons of control boards in real world applications which have relays driven from MCUs and controlling any kind of AC loads, but without MOV or other type of filters.

So, this is the question:

- Why is my design not working as expected and I need to place MOVs, but similar boards from real world work perfectly without preventing relay contact spikes? What kind of magic are manufacturers doing?

Comment: You could look for differences in the relay circuit, between your design and other designs. First of all, are there any differences in the relays themselves, like better ratings for current break ability or faster disconnect or anything like that? Then, how about the coil kickback suppression? You seem to be using a Schottky diode, which is absolute worst device for regarding the decay of coil magnetism, so the release is slowest and the relay can spend a long time at the point of disconnection.

Comment: The diode I'm using as kickback suppresion is a S1J, wich is an standard rectifier, not a 
 Schottky. Regarding the relay, I'm using a TE Connectivity T77V1D10-12 interfaced via MOSFET.